# some qusetion about ReactiveCocoa.combineLatest?

Tags: ios, swift, reactive-cocoa

I'm learning `Reactivecocoa` The following code used `Rxswift`,but when I use `Reactivecocoa` to achieve，feeling complex.

**RxSwift:**

```
Observable.combineLatest(firstNameLabel.rx_text, lastNameLabel.rx_text) { $0 + " " + $1 }
        .bindTo(greetingLabel.rx_text)
        .addDisposeBag(disposeBag)
```

**Reactivecocoa:**

```
        let a = self.money.rac_textSignal().map { text in text as! String}
    let b = self.moneyCount.rac_textSignal().map { text in text as! String}
    RACSignal.combineLatest([a, b]).subscribeNext { (value) in
        let stringArry = value as! RACTuple
        let stringAll = (stringArry.first as! String) + (stringArry.second as! String)
    }
```

How do I modify code in Reactivacocoa,please

Comment: I cannot decipher your question. What are you asking?

Comment: Take a look at [this doc](https://github.com/ReactiveCocoa/ReactiveCocoa/blob/master/Documentation/BasicOperators.md#combining-latest-values). Also, the real world example using `combineLatest` could be found in [this app, called Giraffe](https://github.com/evgeniyd/Giraffe)